# Wrap text failed inside a table and grid container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

Here is my code i wanna break the text once it beyond the <Grid item xs={12} sm={9} zeroMinWidth style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word' }}> and the wordWrap: 'break-word' does not work.

```
<Table striped style={{ tableLayout: 'fixed',wordWrap: 'break-word',overflowX:"auto"}}>
    <thead style={{height:"45px"}}>
        <tr>
            <Grid container >
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
                    <th style={{ width: '23%' }}>name</th>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={9} >
                    <th>information</th>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        {Items.map((item, index) => (
            <tr>
                <Grid container >
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
                        <td >
                        <p style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>abc</p>
                        </td>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={9} zeroMinWidth style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word' }}>
                        <div style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word' }}>
                            <td style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word' }}>
                                <JSONPretty id="json-pretty" data={item.body}></JSONPretty>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                                            
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

[image]
I expect if the text goes beyond the the grid or <div style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word' }}> then the text will be broken and wrapped to next line so the paragraph will be extended vertically.

Added whiteSpace property
[Added whiteSpace property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkaVt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to break lines when it exceeds the td width.
So, what you should be looking for is whitespace property.

To wrap paragraph you can just use

```
<td style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>
    <JSONPretty id="json-pretty" data={item.body}></JSONPretty>
</td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi wanna ask why using whiteSpace property but not wordWrap property i cant differentiate the difference between them

Comment: hi Shahriar Rumel your suggestion does not work please view my new attactments

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. Can you try it with overflow-wrap: break-word ? And you may put that on the div that's wrapping the text as well.

Comment: And also explicitly set the table width.